# Video Thumbnails are not getting populated in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I'm making recycler view which fetches the video thumbnails horizontally which is checked in the previous activity. 
I've used Log everywhere to find whether the method is working or not. The method is working fine the main problem I'm getting is after all the efforts the video thumbnails are not getting populated in the space provided or I must say the area is blank. Nothing in it.

This is my custom layout which inflates the recycler view :

**1. custom_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#212326"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/></LinearLayout>
```

Now the editvideo activity which fetches the checked file from the previous fragment.

**2. EditVideoActivity.java**

```
public class EditVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton filterButton,cutButton,audioButton;

ArrayList<File> mList = new ArrayList<>();
ListView mListView;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

ViewAdapter viewAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_video);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.edit_header_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    filterButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.filterVideo);
    cutButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cutVideo);
    audioButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.musicalNotes);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.videoGallery);
    //checking out for received data
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String receivedData = extras.getString("sendData");
    Log.e("RECEIVED DATA=====", receivedData);
    String filename;

    for(int i=0;i<receivedData.substring(1,receivedData.length()-1).split(",").length;i++){
        filename = receivedData.split(",")[i];
        File file = new File(filename);
        Log.e("FILENAME===",filename);
        mList.add(file);
    }
    viewAdapter = new ViewAdapter(mList);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(EditVideoActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);


    audioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditVideoActivity.this, AudioActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_video, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.moveNext:
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditVideoActivity.this,PreviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(false);
}
```

The ViewAdapter class is here :

**3. ViewAdapter class**

```
 class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private View rootView;
    ArrayList<File> files;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public ViewAdapter(ArrayList<File>items) {
        files = items;
        Log.e("ADAPTER","CONSTRUCTOR CALLED");
        //inflating the layout
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Log.e("ADAPTER","VIEW HOLDER CREATED");
       rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_listview,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("ADAPTER",files.get(position).toString());

        if (files != null) {

            bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(files.get(position).toString(),1);
        }

        holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       // holder.mImageView.setId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return files.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
} }
```

The problem is onBindViewHolder section **if** because the files is not getting loaded because of bitmap object i'm using. Any help would be highly appreciated

**EDITS : **

In the onBindViewHolder I tested with Log in the if method. What I got is NullPointerException. It means it is not making any thumbnails.

here it goes :

```
if(files != null){
   bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createThumbnail(files.get(position).toString(),1);
Log.e("FILES======",bitmap.toString());
}
```

**Error in Logcat when used Log.e below the bitmap definition**

```
08-08 16:34:12.548 22000-22000/in.pinelane.myhovi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: in.pinelane.myhovi, PID: 22000
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at in.pinelane.myhovi.EditVideoActivity$ViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(EditVideoActivity.java:149)
                                                                    at in.pinelane.myhovi.EditVideoActivity$ViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(EditVideoActivity.java:118)
```

Comment: Check that `files.get(position).toString()` is giving you what you expect. It looks like `createThumbnail()` will return null for any error encountered. The path could be wrong or the format may not be supported.

Comment: I've checked the file, the file is correct just it is showing me the single file. Here the logcat report for you :                                                                                               
**08-08 17:19:19.596 31495-31495/in.pinelane.myhovi E/ADAPTER: [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20170720_185436141.mp4**

Comment: one more thing this file is already in mp4 format in the previous activity and is created in thumbnails only. M just calling it from the previous activity.

Comment: Are you saying that the file is already in a thumbnail format? If so, are you trying to convert a thumbnail to a thumbnail? Would that be supported?

Comment: Well yes thumbnail is already present. What I've to do is to populate the selected thumbnails in the **EditVideoActivity.java**, if you have any way then please suggest. My requirement is that only.

Comment: I suggest that you place the app in debug and follow execution in `createVideoThumbnail()` to find out why it is failing. The method is not all that involved. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.java#L146).

Comment: I still didn't get you, could you please help me this. I've changed some code. I've used the decodeFile in place of createThumbnails. the code goes like this. but nothing is shown in recyclerview .                                                           **if (files != null) {

                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files.get(position).getPath());
                //Log.e("FILES====", bitmap.toString());
            }**

Comment: It doesn't look like `createVideoThumbnail()` is creating a thumbnail for you. If the path is correct then `createVideoThumbnail()` is failing. You need to find out why it is failing. Unfortunately, from what I can tell, that method doesn't really report errors. It just returns null.  I am suggesting that you use the debugger to see why `createVideoThumbnail()` is failing. Once you know that, you can address the underlying issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151395/discussion-between-alok-and-cheticamp).